# NetBeans not liking libraries in lib-src

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans

I'm working on a project with a group that is using Eclipse, but I'm using Netbeans. Up until today this wasn't an issue. When updating from the repo they have added some source code as a library under a directory called `/lib-src`. When I try to compile the code I get an error that it can't find certain packages... these are the packages under `/lib-src`.

Using NetBeans I can add the library as a folder so now the references to those packages are happy. However, I'm getting this new error when compiling:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:753)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDataItem.addStaticField(ClassDataItem.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefItem.addStaticField(ClassDefItem.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processFields(CfTranslator.java:159)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:130)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:297)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:276)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:228)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:190)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:87)
/home/aaron/NetBeansProjects/xbmc-remote/nbproject/build-impl.xml:411: exec returned: 3
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 25 seconds)
```

I can include the build-impl.xml file if you need it, but I don't think that is main issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there some kind of recursive self-reference thing going on?

Comment: @JRL... that's what I'm thinking. I just figured out how to add lib-src as another source folder (instead of a library) and STILL got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `dx.bat` somehow involved, as in [this thread](http://forum.casmul.com/viewtopic.php?p=14&sid=0f97599d6bd8ec0effa80b913b6dce5b#p14)?

> It seems that Android built tools do not use `ANT_OPTS` variable while running dex tool.
>   Problem can be solved by uncommenting line in `dx.bat` batch file.
>
> You can find it in android SDK folder under `platforms/YOUR_PLATFORM/tools/dx.bat`.
>   At the very end of file there is commented command to increase heap space.
>   Uncommenting this line should solve the problem. Line should looks like this:

```
set javaOpts=-Xmx256M
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try making the heap space bigger by adding "-Xmx512m" as a JRE command line argument. This can be done permanently by editing netbeans.conf (or via the JRE options through the IDE).

`netbeans.conf` is is located in the etc directory of your netbeans installation directory.
The JRE options used by NetBeans can be accessed by right clicking your project in NetBeans, selecting Properties -> Run -> VM Options.

Comment: Where is that file located? I can't find JRE Options anywhere under Tools -> Options. Where do I go to set that in the IDE?